# Booting an installed Ubuntu in an USB from Windows 8.1

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb, sd-card

So I have bought an Asus Transformer Pad T100 and it contains Windows 8.1. It also has a Micro SD card slot that contains a 16GB Micro SD card. So I have installed Ubuntu on the card and now is it possible to boot to that Micro SD card? If it's possible then how?

P/S: I tried go to the BIOS menu and it didn't show the SD card sadly D:

Comment: It may not boot Ubuntu?  http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQ5NzE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find the SD Card as a boot option in your bios, it may be unlikely that you can boot to it.  The bios has an option to search for and specify which drive to boot to.  Most modern computers will include a USB slot (or pen drive) as a boot option.  You might consider getting a pen drive.  You can likely find one twice the size for around 10 dollars on a place like Amazon.

When you installed Ubuntu on the card, the install would have automatically added it to your boot menu (along with your Windows 8) if you had access to choose it as your boot drive.

Choosing which drive will contain the boot loader is one of features that happens as part of the installation.  So, I'm certain that part is already done.  It's just that your bios doesn't appear to support booting to the SD card.

You could alternatively install grub on your computer's hard drive instead.  Then grub would find all the OS installation and most likely succeed adding the SDCard as a OS Boot option.  But this could present a number of problems.  During it wrong might cause your Windows 8 not to boot.

I'm sure your best bet would be to use a pen drive instead of the SD Card.

Answer (score 0):

Use live Ubuntu and install gparted software and it will mount all the drives as well as microsd card and from there you can format your sd card and it will allocate as free space and then you will to boot another OS.